# WPF multibinding visibility of a grid template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a list view which each listview which contain several columns of data. this list view contain 2 grids, 1 grid which is the header.
and a secound grid which show all the relavent data.per the items
what I am trying to perform is to hide some of the data per properites the value of some fields in the data.

how can I do that? I tried multiyBinding by I am getting an error:

"'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Path' property of type 'Binding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject."

would be happy for a code example

here is the code I have written

```
<ListView x:Name="LVGuiCoreBus" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MouseDown="LVGui_MouseDown"  Grid.Row="1"  VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"  VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"  SelectionChanged="LVGuiCoreBus_SelectionChanged">                                     
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>                      
                <VirtualizingStackPanel >
                    <Grid VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">                           
                        <Grid.Visibility>
                            <MultiBinding>
                                <Binding Path="{Binding Source, Converter={StaticResource VisiblieGroupFilterBySourcecs},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Binding>
                                <Binding Path="{Binding Destination, Converter={StaticResource VisiblieGroupFilterBySourcecs},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Binding>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Grid.Visibility>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="130"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>                                                      
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateNTimeStr}"  Foreground="Green" Grid.Column="0" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source}" Foreground="{Binding Source,Converter={StaticResource CoreBusPanelModuleColorConverter},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="2" Background="{ Binding Source, Converter={StaticResource BackGroundFilterConverterBySource}}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Destination}" Foreground="{Binding Destination,Converter={StaticResource CoreBusPanelModuleColorConverter},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="4" Background="{ Binding Destination, Converter={StaticResource BackGroundFilterConvertorByDestantation}}"  />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Module}" Grid.Column="6" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="{ Binding Module, Converter={StaticResource BackGroundFilterByModule},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Controll}" Grid.Column="8"  Background="{ Binding Controll, Converter={StaticResource BackGRoundFilterByControll},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Command}" Grid.Column="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Background="{ Binding Command, Converter={StaticResource BackGroundFilterByCommand},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding HSCommand}" Grid.Column="12" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Background="{ Binding HSCommand, Converter={StaticResource BackGroundFilterByHsCommand},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data_Str}"  Grid.Column="14" />                                                                
            </Grid>
                </VirtualizingStackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Name="CMMenuCopy">
            <MenuItem x:Name="MCICopyLine" Header="Copy Line" Click="MCICopyLine_Click" ></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem x:Name="MCICopyText" Header="Copy Only Data Array" Click="MCICopyText_Click" ></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem x:Name="MCIClear" Header="Clear" Click="MCIClear_Click"></MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListView.ContextMenu>
</ListView>
```

Comment: You don't want to bind a Binding's Path. What you want is this: `<Binding Path="Source" Converter="{StaticResource VisiblieGroupFilterBySourcecs}"/>`. That said, the VirtualizingStackPanel in the DataTemplate is pointless. It has no effect there.

Comment: how to make update per property change?

Comment: not I got this error:

Answer (score 2):

You should change your code following these two steps:

1. Change your `Binding` markup extension to `Binding` object.
2. Add an `IMultiValueConverter` to your `MultiBinding.

As a result, you can change your `MultiBinding` usage like this:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource YouShouldWriteANewMultiBindingConverterHere}">
    <Binding Path="Source" Converter="{StaticResource VisiblieGroupFilterBySourcecs}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
    <Binding Path="Destination" Converter="{StaticResource VisiblieGroupFilterBySourcecs}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
</MultiBinding>
```

---

First, the `{Binding xxx, Converter=xxx}` is used as a `MarkupExtension` can only be used on a dependency property. But when you use `Binding` in a `MultiBinding`, you're treating it as a `Binding` object instead of a `MarkupExtension`. so you should set the `Binding` properties just like a normal XAML object.

Second, a `MultiBinding` needs an `IMultiValueConverter` or a `StringFormat` property set.

```
public class YouShouldWriteANewMultiBindingConverterHere : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

---

You can learn more about `MarkupExtension`, `MultiBinding`, `IMultiValueConverter` by reading these:

- [Markup Extensions and WPF XAML | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/markup-extensions-and-wpf-xaml)
- [Data Binding Overview | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview)
- [MultiBinding Class (System.Windows.Data) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.multibinding?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [IMultiValueConverter Interface (System.Windows.Data) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter?view=netframework-4.7.2)